# Property on the prototype overrides the property of the actual object?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a `Person` constructor function like so with the method sayHello

```
var Person = function(firstName,lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.sayHello = function() {
    return "Hi there " + firstName;
  }
};
```

Then I define a different version of the sayHello method on the prototype of `Person`:

```
Object.defineProperties(Person.prototype,{
  sayHello: {
    value: function() {
      return 'Hi there';
    },
    enumerable: true
  }
});
```

Now if I create a Person instance and call sayHello on it - I notice that it is using the version of sayHello which is defined on the prototype.

```
var JoeBlow = new Person('Joe','Blow');

> JoeBlow.sayHello() 
< "Hi there" // I was expecting "Hi there Joe"
```

This to me is confusing.

Why doesn't the JoeBlow object use **its own** implementation of sayHello, instead of looking up sayHello on its prototype object?

Comment: I'm not sure but you also try to get return a `firstname` instead of `this.firstname`. possible you missed the `this.firstname = firstname` and then you will be able to get a return. Because it returns `udefined` with a Quentin answer

Comment: @nAz — `firstname` is a variable defined here — `(firstName,lastName)` — and is still in scope for the function expression defined inside the constructor function. I tested the code in my answer and it returns "Hi there Joe".

Comment: @Quentin yeap you are right, possible i missed something, that's why i tested it and was suprised. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, properties defined with `defineProperties` are *read only*.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

> **writable**
>  true if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed with an assignment operator.
>  Defaults to
>   false.

Unfortunately, when you attempt to set a read only property in old style JS, it fails silently rather than throwing an exception, so this is really hard to debug.

If you had run this in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) you would have got:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'sayHello' of [object Object]

You can explicitly define the property to be writable.

```
Object.defineProperties(Person.prototype,{
  sayHello: {
    value: function() {
      return 'Hi there';
    },
    enumerable: true,
    writable: true
  }
});
```

Then `this.sayHello = function() {` won't fail silently and you'll successfully mask the version of the property living on the prototype.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but how does this answer why the property lookup resolves to use the prototype version instead of the original version? How does **writable** effect the version on the object itself(or rather forces the engine to use the prototype version instead)

Comment: @AmmarCSE — The prototype version **is** the original version. The replacement version that the constructor function is trying to overwrite it with is failing because the property is read only. Making the property writable allows `this.sayHello = something` to successfully assign a new value.

Comment: wait, are you saying that `Person.prototype` is `Person` itself? I thought, in this case, it would be `Object`

Comment: @AmmarCSE — Err, that isn't what I'm saying. When you create an instance of a Prototype object, the new object that is created gets all the properties from the prototype.

Comment: I think that what Quentin means is that property assignments fail when an object inherits a property with the same name which is read-only... @Quentin is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh, I see now, when `new Person` is called, `sayHello` already exists on the prototype and is read-only by default. Makes sense now! Thanks guys

Comment: It's really weird that `console.log(this.sayHello = function() {
    return "Hi there " + firstName;
  } );` returns the function that failed to be set as the value of the`sayHello` property

Comment: @JuanMendes — See [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1) — Assignment operator expressions (unconditionally) evaluate as the RHS outside of strict mode.